# Classic Hello World

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a classic "Hello World" program in Ruby.  I have tried a lot but in [codewars](http://www.codewars.com/), my solutions didn't work.

Here is the description of my task:

> The main mode is having a method named main inside a class and should return nothing but should print a line to the standard output with the message Hello World!

How do I do this in Ruby?

Comment: To output to console in ruby: `puts 'Hello world!'`

Comment: You'll need to add something in the way of code to this question or it's asking us to speculate on what you've done.

Comment: It is impossible to return nothing from a properly working Ruby code. At the most trivial, you can return `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

This should meet the requirements that you described:

```
class HelloWorld
  def self.main
    puts "Hello World"
  end
end

HelloWorld.main
```

However, it's nearly all unnecessary; you can simply use a one-line program:

```
puts "Hello World"
```

Comment: The "[When in Rome](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/when_in_Rome,_do_as_the_Romans_do)" principle applies here. In Ruby it's extremely unusual to have a `main` method. Any coding exercise that requires you to create one was surely created by someone not entirely familiar with the spirit and culture of Ruby.